# Passthrough of virtual devices through Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, usb, remote-desktop, webcam, obs-studio

One of the features of Windows Remote Desktop is device passthrough, which allows for an easy way to provide a remote machine with access to devices. Unfortunately it looks as though this is only for USB devices based on what I could find online. One of the things I'm trying to do is utilize the virtual webcam feature in Open Broadcast Software (OBS). My intention is to be able to utilize the virtual camera through the remote computer I connect to with RDP.

Is there any way I could achieve this, maybe through a tool that could make the virtual camera look like a hardware camera?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little more digging, I was able to find the following software that are capable of making a virtual camera that Remote Desktop can detect:

- e2eSoft VCam
- ManyCam
- AlterCam

Note: Unfortunately these are all paid software, but I am leaving this here as they are solutions and may be able to help someone out. Between the three of these, ManyCam seems to be the best. The other two might be a little outdated.

[image]